# Every time I search for a country it creates a new map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

As a beginner I am trying to create a map with JavaScript using OpenLayers
for coordinates I am using REST countries API.
When I search for a country it creates a new map every time. If I search 5 countries there are five maps in a row. but it should only be changing marker on the map according to coordinates.

Code is somthing like this:

```js
     const input = document.getElementById("search");
  function openMap(longitude, latitude,) {
  
    var attribution = new ol.control.Attribution({
      collapsible: false,
    });
  
    map = new ol.Map({
      controls: ol.control.defaults({ attribution: false }).extend([attribution]),
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM({
            attributions: [
              ol.source.OSM.ATTRIBUTION,
            ],
            maxZoom: 10,
          }),
        }),
      ],
      target: "map",
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([latitude, longitude]),
        maxZoom: 4,
        zoom: 3,
      }),
    });
   
    var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [
          new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
              ol.proj.fromLonLat([latitude, longitude])
            ),
          }),
        ],
      }),
    });
  
    map.addLayer(layer);
    layer.removeAll;
  
    var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
      autoPan: true,
      autoPanAnimation: {
        duration: 250,
      },
    });
    map.addOverlay(overlay)
}

 input.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
      fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all").then((response) => {
        response.json().then((json) => {
          json.forEach((country) => {
            // console.log(country);
            if(e.target.value === country.name){
              console.log(country.latlng[0],country.latlng[1]);
              openMap(country.latlng[0],country.latlng[1]) // here i am calling openLayer's function  
                
              
            }
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: Obviously you are creating new map with each `openMap` call. Please edit your question and add code for `openMap` function.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With each search you are creating a new map with the call to the `openMap` function. You have to create map only once at the first search. On subsequent searches just clear old country center point feature, add new center point and center map to that point.

Code could then look something like this:

```
const input = document.getElementById("search");

var map;
var layer;

function addCountryCenterPoint(lonLat) {
  var pointFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(lonLat)
  });
  var source = layer.getSource();
  source.clear();
  source.addFeature(pointFeature);
}

function openMap(lonLat) {
  var attribution = new ol.control.Attribution({
    collapsible: false,
  });
  map = new ol.Map({
    controls: ol.control.defaults({ attribution: false }).extend([attribution]),
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM({
          attributions: [
            ol.source.OSM.ATTRIBUTION,
          ],
          maxZoom: 10,
        }),
      }),
    ],
    target: "map",
    view: new ol.View({
      center: lonLat,
      maxZoom: 4,
      zoom: 3,
    }),
  });
  layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector()
  });
  addCountryCenterPoint(lonLat);
  map.addLayer(layer);
}

input.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all").then((response) => {
    response.json().then((json) => {
      json.forEach((country) => {
        if(e.target.value === country.name){
          var lonLat = ol.proj.fromLonLat([country.latlng[1], country.latlng[0]]);
          if (!map)
            openMap(lonLat);
          else {
            addCountryCenterPoint(lonLat);
            map.getView().setCenter(lonLat);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thankyou so much it worked perfectly.